# How is the itk::SmartPointer converted to bool?

Tags: c++, boolean, implicit-conversion, itk

The [smart pointer used by the ITK library](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/itkSmartPointer_8h_source.html) can be implicitly converted to `bool`, for example in an `if` clause. It's very convenient, but I'd like to make sure how it works. My guess is that C++ uses the provided `operator==` to compare to 0, but I couldn't find any documentation describing this behavior. Is this really what's happening?
[Here](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1SmartPointer.html) is the Doxygen page for the class, for people who might find it more convenient than the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conversion operator

```
   operator ObjectType *() const
        { return m_Pointer; }
```

allows implicit conversion to a pointer type, which can in turn be converted to `bool`.

While it works, this is generally regarded as a bad idea: if you're not careful you can accidentally store a non-smart pointer, liable to be invalidated when the smart pointer destroys its object. For this reason, standard smart pointers instead have an `explicit operator bool()` to allow use in a boolean context, and an explicit `get()` function for when you really want a non-smart pointer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I do see the danger in having implicit conversion to raw pointer, but at least I know now.